# conflicts after merging branches. Files are the Same, but intellij git Says They are Different

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge

I have merged `foo branch` into `baar branch` as discriped [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/merging-deleting-and-comparing-branches.html). After merging, intellij git shows 300 files which contain conflicts. When I compare these files, I notice that some of them are the same. I can not recognize between two files, they are really the same.  How to deal with this issue? I really hope somebody can help

Comment: Are you sure it is not a whitespace or new lines issue?

Comment: no. How to deal if it is a whitespace or new lines? any possibility to ignore whitespace?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Answer (score 0):

In the diff viewer of IntelliJ you can select to ignore the white spaces and new lines as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/differences-viewer.html#d1072733e159). If the files are actually the same this should solve all your problems, and they are too many files to do this manually you can merge from the console with the following command:

```
git merge -Xignore-space-change
```

Then in IntelliJ you will only see the files that are really conflicting. Bare in mind that if different developers are using different formatters you might get a lot of unnecessary conflicts, and you should agree on using the same one. For example there is no straight forward way git can know that this:

```
void foo() {}
```

Is the same as this:

```
void foo()
{
}
```

If that is the case I would suggest you to auto-format all conflicting code in both branches before merging to actually see the differences.